# How to delete line from file (PHP)

Tags: php, file

```
    $file = file($dir);
    $string = 'mystring';
    foreach($file as $key=>$value) {
        if(!strcmp($value, $string)) {
           unset($file[$key]);
        }
    }
```

Why unset only last string and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

> Note: 
>   Each line in the resulting array will include the line ending, unless FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES is used, so you still need to use rtrim() if you do not want the line ending present.

So, either:

```
$file = file($dir,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Or:

```
if(!strcmp(rtrim($value), $string)) {
```

Would probably work (assuming the the trailing newlines are indeed the cause why they don't match until the very last line).

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear what you want to achieve. Strcmp only compares the two strings and returns whether or not the first string is larger than the second.

The unset is the way to go once you have selected with line in the file to delete

Answer (score 0):

To go along with the previous two, to ignore whitespace at either end, this may be more what you're looking for:

```
if(trim($value) !== $string) {
```